# Maven, Proguard and JDK8

Tags: java-8, proguard, android-maven-plugin

I'm trying to [contribute to the Parceler library](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/pull/102) but I'm having issues with maven android plugin, obfuscation and jdk8.

It is well known [issue](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/144/) and I've tried to fix it by installing latest tool and [specifying](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/proguard-mojo.html#proguard) specific `proguard.jar` path. But looks like it is still [failing](https://travis-ci.org/johncarl81/parceler/jobs/68306471). So looking if someone can lead me in the right direction.

Meanwhile I'm digging more.

**UPD** 
Here is error that I have:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [com/oracle/net/Sdp$1.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7))
[INFO]  at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:112)
[INFO]  at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
[INFO]  at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
[INFO]  at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
[INFO]  at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
[INFO]  at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
[INFO]  ... 6 more
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)
[INFO]  at proguard.classfile.util.ClassUtil.checkVersionNumbers(ClassUtil.java:140)
[INFO]  at proguard.classfile.io.LibraryClassReader.visitLibraryClass(LibraryClassReader.java:89)
[INFO]  at proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.accept(LibraryClass.java:301)
[INFO]  at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:86)
[INFO]  ... 11 more
```

Comment: It doesn’t seem to use your updated version. But even if it did; what does it help when Android is not capable of using the newer class files anyway?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Proguard builds list of classes but some of them (the contracts) are identical for android and some are not used at all. I wonder how to check that maven plugin uses latest proguard

Comment: The android maven plugin invokes proguard via the Android SDK and as such you have to check for a working version there.

Comment: @ManfredMoser thanks, so maven plugin relies only on proguard in Android SDK

Comment: Check out the proguard mojo to be sure ... either the SDK directly or the dependencies from the SDK team.  See https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/simpligility/maven/plugins/android/phase04processclasses/ProguardMojo.java

Answer (score 0):

Update ProGuard to latest version in Android SDK 'tools' folder from link http://proguard.sourceforge.net/downloads.html